# Storage.prototype.setObject declaration type

Tags: typescript

I am struggling to write a `d.ts` for the following dom feature

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key:string, value:any) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key:string) {
    var value = this.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
}
```

How should I extend the default dom Storage definition type for the following?

[image: vscode]

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to extend `Storage` interface:

```
interface Storage {
    setObject<T>(key:string, value:T):void;
    getObject<T>(key:string):T;
}
```

For specifying function's `this` type you can use fake `this` parameter (should be the first one):

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(this:Storage, key:string, value:any) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(this:Storage, key:string) {
    var value = this.getItem(key);
    return value && JSON.parse(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! ps any tips about how to assigning a type annotation to `this`

Comment: Sorry didn't get your question. What you mean by _how to assigning a type annotation to this_?

Comment: The only 2 errors left after adding the Storage interface is the two `this` type errors. Don't know how to give `this` a type also